# How to prove or disprove that if $x \equiv c \mod n $ then $ x \equiv -c \mod n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am studying modular arithmetic and I don't know how to prove or disprove the following :

If $x \equiv c \mod n $ then $x \equiv -c \mod n$

By trying different numbers it seems as this is true ,some attempt I've made so far is :

$x \equiv c \mod n \implies x \equiv -(-c) \mod n $

Since $-x \equiv -c \mod n $  I have that $$ x \equiv -(-x) \mod n \implies 0\equiv 0 \mod n $$

What does the last statement now mean ?

Comment: Did you try some specific numbers? It should be fairly clear, either from the definition of $\equiv$ or the final step you have that this is false.

Comment: I've picked up the wrong numbers then ...

Comment: You must have only picked $n=2$ or $x=nm$ for it to be true.

Comment: Try doing this with $n=3$; what does that give you?

Comment: Before the edit, you had come to the conclusion that $2x \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Write down *any* number for which this is false.

Comment: @Bongers that was a typo I didn't notice

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh I see ,that would have been easier to deal with .... thanks for noticing.

Comment: However,isn't $0 \equiv 0 \mod n $ always true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod 2, $1\equiv-1$ and the $\iff$ is true. When the mod $n$ is $>2$, $1\not\equiv-1$ and the $\iff$  is false.